# Offline slony installation on enterprise database 13.1

Tags: postgresql, installation, offline, slony, edb

I have been using Windows 10 operating system. I want to use slony master-slave setup with postgresql. For this, I have downloaded enterprise database 13.1 version. After installation I select slony download from stackbuilder plus. Then I copied these 2 files to offline windows 10 machine. I install both of them. After that, i try to run a simple slonik script to setup master. while executing "init cluster" command i get file not found error, c:servershare/slony1_base.2.8.sql. Do you have an idea for the solution?

Comment: It's unusual to select a "thanks" answer as the accepted answer. You should consider accepting your own answer, which appears to have an actual solution in it.

Answer (score 0):

After setting SLONY_SHARE_DIR to the location that the slony1 .sql files are in, everything works fine.